# how to execute a function more than once and concatenate its outputs into an array only in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to create a function that calls a function that I already have to execute it N times and then concatenate in its array only its outputs. this is the function that I want to perform more than once.

```
def r_sample(m_base, m_external):
    n_linhas_m_base = m_base.shape[0] # matriz com as variáveis do detector central
    n_linhas_m_external = m_external.shape[0] # matriz com as variáveis dos prótons
    index_m_external = [i for i in range(n_linhas_m_external)]
    mask = random.sample(index_m_external, k=n_linhas_m_base)
    m_sampled = np.concatenate((m_base, m_external[mask, :]), axis=1)
    return m_sampled
```

Isso vai me retornar um numpy array de dimensão (NxM). O que eu preciso é de uma função (ou apenas um código) que execute esse *r_sample* 10 ou 20 vezes, mas que não produza 10 ou 20 arrays separados, Eu preciso deles juntos, num array só.
Tipo assim, a saída da função r_sample é assim:

```
array( [[ 1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]])
```

Next, I would like something like that

```
array( [[ 1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9],
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9],
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]])
```

In this example, I ran the r_sample code 3 times

Comment: What do you mean by calling it N times? in for loop or recursive function inside it?

Comment: For example. I want to execute the function N = 5 times

Answer (score 1):

you can call this function which takes as input your array and the number of times you want to concatenate it:

```
def self_concatenate(array,nb_concat)
    result = array
    for i in range(nb_concat-1):
        result = np.concatenate((result, array), axis=0)
    return result
```

Comment: The execution of the function is correct, but I wanted a solution in which my r_sample function would generate different arrays for each execution. It is returning me the same output array as r_sample and concatenating. As the result of this r_sample function is an array with some random columns, I would need this result also random for each execution

Comment: you want the number of concatenation to be random? 
that's it?

Comment: I managed to solve it by doing a simple loop and then starting. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable called `all_arrays` which is an empty array. Where you call the function you could put a loop. Then you can get hold of the functions callback and add the `current_array` `to all_arrays` like this: `all_arrays += current_array`. The whole code can look something like this:

```
all_arrays = []
for _ in range(8):
    current_array = r_sample(m_base, m_external)
    all_arrays += current_array
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: This gave the following error:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (3,2)